# Android - Navigation Component - Removing access from previous screens on Sign Out

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have an Android app (Java) that uses Navigation Component with a single activity (MainActivity).

Currently navigation is handled as follows:

***SplashScreenFragment*** (this is the Start Destination)

navigates to

***WelcomeFragment*** (here I have **popUpTo SplashScreenFragment, inclusive**)

navigates to

***SignInFragment***

navigates to

***HomeFragment*** (here I have **popUpTo WelcomeFragment, inclusive**)

(Home Fragment is one of four fragments that use Bottom Navigation)

As soon as the user moves to HomeFragment, the toolbar and bottom navigation become visible. The toolbar has a sign out button which can be accessed from any of these 4 fragments or any other subfragments.

When the user clicks on Sign Out, the app navigates back to the WelcomeFragment. Obviously the user should not be able to move back to the previous screen.

The problem is, I can sign out from any fragment so I don't have a fixed action in the nav_graph for this, and thus, I can't add popUpTo.

This is how the MainActivity handles navigation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.libraryFragment, R.id.searchFragment, R.id.myStuffFragment).build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);


    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.splashScreenFragment || destination.getId() == R.id.welcomeFragment || destination.getId() == R.id.signInFragment) {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.right_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        // other cases...

        case R.id.signout:
            openSignOutDialog();
            break;

    }

    return true;

}


private void openSignOutDialog() {
    SignOutDialog dialog = new SignOutDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sign out dialog");
}


@Override
public void onConfirm() {
    // remove from SharedPreferences

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController.navigate(R.id.welcomeFragment);
}
```

I tried adding navController.popBackStack but that just closes the application.

How can I return to the Welcome screen and prevent the user from going backwards to the previous screen?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to define action from your current fragment to destination fragment.
Then you need to write in your current fragment:

findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_name)

Comment: But there is no particular current fragment. The sign out button can be called from anywhere in the app and clicks to the SignOut button are handled by the MainActivity.